# iOS - create a UI to see users who like our post

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I need advice to create user interface like this UI.

[image: Facebook UI when see likers]

Is it better to use `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` because its display is row based? But, when I swipe left and right, it has different section like the collection view horizontal scroll. It makes me confused because I have never created such a UI. I prefer to use `UITableViewController`, but when I see the segment, I can't use segmented controller because I can't swipe to change the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create storyboard view controller (UIViewController). Controller's view has two subviews: title view and container view (two IBOutlet views).

2) Title view - it's a top view (in your case - collection view with items).
Container view - it's a view for pageViewController.
You will do something like this:

```
self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
                                                          navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                                                        options:nil];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.pageViewController.delegate = self;

[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[[self viewControllerForIndex:index]]
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO
                                 completion:nil];
[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.containerView addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    UITableViewController *vc = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    return vc;
}
```

Comment: so, i use PageViewController for the storyboard, and i use UITableViewController? I still don`t understand about the top view, is it a new CollectionViewController ?

Comment: @calvinsugianto i refactored my answer, hope it would be more clearly.

Comment: what self.pageViewController refered to ? Is it a new property defined like this?

    (at)IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    (at)IBOutlet weak var titleView: UIView!

    var pageViewController = UIPageViewController()

Comment: @calvinsugianto yes, you are right. It's just a view controller with these properties. Instead outlet you create and add as subview page view controller via code (code above).

Comment: ok, i`m begin to understand now, so i implement pageViewController in my code, not add it in my storyboard, after that, i make a tableViewController in my storyboard for being controlled in my pageViewController (container View), after that, i add UICollectionView inside my titleView in my storyboard. The structure is like this -> titleView has UICollectionView, containerView has UIPageViewController (by code) which has child controller of UITableViewController (different view controller). So, Totally, i make 2 ViewController (1 View Controller and 1 TableViewController).

Comment: it's right, but it's not nessasary to create storyboard view controller for table view, You can just create UIViewController and add table view as subview manually via code.

Comment: how do i manage my tableViewCell without create new TableviewController in storyboard? i must place imageView, label, or some button for add Friend (including constraint).

Comment: you can create / configure cell via .xib without storyboard

Comment: nice, i'm doing it right now, i created uitableviewcontroller with .xib , but the weird part is, i can't modify the cell (can`t add imageview,label,etc). I think the only choice is to make UIviewController with .xib and add tableView as a subview

Comment: No no, don't create .xib for ViewController with table view. Create .xib for UITableViewCell.

Comment: it works! next, i must set the animation of horizontal scroll bar in titleView (collectionView) to tell user which tableView they picked because they still no horizontal scroll bar yet (underline below like/love icon)

Comment: I think now it's not necessary to create this animation. Just create simple highlight and implement full view controller logic. Then, when you really will need to configure this animation I will try to help you!